# Page navigation consumes memory

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I use several XAML pages and navigate between them inside a frame on a main page using Frame.Navigate(Type pageType) function.
This works nicely, but each opened page increases memory usage.

I tried to clean BackStack of the frame after each opened page, tried to use GoBack and GoForward functions instead of Navigate function, but memory usage always grows.

As far as I can understand, each page navigation keeps something in memory, but I cannot guess what should be freed to stop memory usage growth.

Comment: Can you provide the exact memory consumed by a page?

Comment: 20 kB .. 200 kB depending on the XAML contents of a page. 20 kB if page is almost empty, 200 kB if several lists and buttons are present.

Comment: I am not referring to the `page.cs` file size.

Comment: Of course these are memory usage data, not file sizes. For example 5 page transitions increase memory allocated by application by 1 MB. If page is almost empty (contains only one TextBlock) then 45 page transitions increase memory usage by 1 MB. Garbage collection does not free this memory.